# RoleProvider .NET 2 - converted from MS Access to MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, membership-provider

I have an old site running on .NET 2 using an AccessMembershipProvide and I'm changing it to MySqlMemebrshipProvider - The membership side works fine, but the roles part seems to not provide the roles methods?

If I switch back to the OdbcRoleProvide in the Web.Config it works while still using the MySqlMembershipProvider.

I'm calling the roles with: `Response.Write(Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Admin") & " -role exist- " & Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))`

this returns `false` even with logged in user.?

NOTE: I'm running it on a hosted site and don't have access to Visual Studio (I know this makes debugging incredibly difficult)!!!

Web.Config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<clear />
<add name="OdbcServices" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=e:\App_Data\subsite.mdb;" />
<add name="ConnString" connectionString="Database=Training;Data Source=localhost;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>

<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
    <codeSubDirectories>
        <add directoryName="VBCode" />
        <add directoryName="CSCode" />
    </codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>
<!--
<membership defaultProvider="AccessMembershipProvider"
            userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AccessMembershipProvider"
 type="AccessMembershipProvider"
 enablePasswordReset="true"
 enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
 connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\App_Data\subsite.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
 />
  </providers>

</membership>

<roleManager defaultProvider="OdbcRoleProvider"
    enabled="true"
    cacheRolesInCookie="true"
    cookieName=".ASPROLES"
    cookieTimeout="30"
    cookiePath="/"
    cookieRequireSSL="false"
    cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
    cookieProtection="All" >

  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="OdbcRoleProvider"
      type="Samples.AspNet.Roles.OdbcRoleProvider"
      connectionStringName="OdbcServices"
      applicationName="SampleApplication"
      writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />

  </providers>

</roleManager>
-->

<!-- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12301/Membership-and-Role-providers-for-MySQL -->

<roleManager defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider"
    enabled="true"
    cacheRolesInCookie="true"
    cookieName=".ASPROLES"
    cookieTimeout="30"
    cookiePath="/"
    cookieRequireSSL="false"
    cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
    cookieProtection="All" >
<providers>
    <clear />
    <add
        name="MySqlRoleProvider"
        type="Andri.Web.MySqlRoleProvider"
        connectionStringName="ConnString"
        applicationName="SampleApplication"
        writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"
    />
</providers>
</roleManager>

<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider" 
            userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add
            name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
            type="Andri.Web.MySqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="ConnString"
            applicationName="ApplicationName"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
            requiresUniqueEmail="false"
            passwordFormat="Clear"
            writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"
        />
  </providers>
</membership>


<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
</authentication>

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why reverting back to RolesProvider.vb did not cause the same response, however there was an erroneous SQL statement in the MembershipProvider.cs. This resolved the problem and the RolesProvider is responding as desired.