# RoleProvider Class responds randomly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having an issue with my membership and roles class to loading at random times. I'm converting from a MS Access DB to MySql DB. in doing this I needed older parts of my page to use the AccessMembershipProvider and the current to use MySqlMembershipProvider (and RoleProvider)

The membership provider is working fine (I think), it the RolesProvider that seems to be intermittent - when it works it works fine, but after sitting awhile, it seems to note load the Roles Class until I edit the RolesProvider.cs class - than it works fine until another delay.

I have split my App_Code folder to accommodate both .vb and .cs class files.

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
<codeSubDirectories>
    <add directoryName="VBCode" />
    <add directoryName="CSCode" />
</codeSubDirectories>
</compilation>
```

I have added Import myroleprovider.web thinking the issue might be related to: [Error BC30002 - Type XXX is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85091/error-bc30002-type-xxx-is-not-defined/85431#85431)

This all seems related to my previous question that is still unresolved:
[RoleProvider .NET 2 - converted from MS Access to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191498/roleprovider-net-2-converted-from-ms-access-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved due to an error in the MembershipProvider Class that was not being executed - the split App_Code folder is working fine and not the issue. The RoleProvider Class was not the problem either.